# DynamoDB - Combine two table properties (columns) for a PartitionKey?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, primary-key

I'm designing my first DynamoDB database for a financial app where users create several financial portfolios, which contain objects like accounts, investments, transactions, etc. I'm not 100% clear on the best practices for partition keys.

I have 2 questions for the following use cases:

1.) A majority of tables consist of rows where each user in the app will have around 10 to 200 objects, per portfolio (accounts e.g. investments). Since I load data by userId and portfolioId, the userId is the first part of the partition key. However, is it better to create a sort key for the portfolioId or should that be concatenated with the userId?

```
1.1) PartitionKey: userId, SortKey: portfolioId
or
1.2) PartitionKey: userId + portfolioId
```

2.) Transactions in a portfolio will have a much larger number per users, with ranges between 10,000 and 250,000. Again, is concat better, especially given that not all transactions are loaded at once, but only the most recent (based on transactionDate)?

```
2.1) PartitionKey: userId, SortKey: portfolioId
or
2.2) PartitionKey: userId + portfolioId, SortKey: transactionDate
```

Since my get methods will only get the most recent transactions, an additional filter is used on transactionDate.

--> My understanding would be that 1.2 and 2.2 are better designs as they should make retrieving data quicker while still spreading data data uniformly across partitions, since the key starts with a userId, which the app should have many of. 
Any advice or experience with this is much appreciated!

---

```
UPDATE:
```

I wasn't clear enough about the tables. There is a portfolio table where you can query all portfolios by userId, from there the app loads only one portfolio at a time.

There is no need to query all portfolios on tables such as account. Given that, is are 1.2 and 2.2 this still not a good pattern ?

For the 'accounts' table with columns

```
1.1)
accountId,
userId,        --> PartitionKey
portFolioId,   --> SortKey
accountName,
accountType,
...

1.2)
accountId,
userId + portFolioId, --> PartitionKey
accountName,
accountType,
...
```

For 'transactions'

```
2.1)
transactionId,
userId,        --> PartitionKey
portFolioId,   --> SortKey
transactionDate,     
amount,
accountSourceId, 
accountTargetId,
...

2.2)
transactionId,
userId + portFolioId, --> PartitionKey
transactionDate,      --> SortKey   
amount,
accountSourceId, 
accountTargetId,
...
```

Comment: A few thoughts: as I understand your requirements ... 1.2 won't allow you to query for all portfolios for a given user, so 1.1 seems more appropriate. 2.1 won't allow you to query for recent transactions. 2.2 won't allow you to query for recent transactions for a given user, but it will be OK if you always query for recent transactions for a given user *and* given portfolio.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want 1.1. It allows you to perform a Query on the userId and get all portfolios for that user. 1.2. is an anti-pattern, the userId is performing no useful function, you need the userId *and* the portfolioId to get an item. In this case you would be better of simply using the profolioId at the partition key.

For part 2, you probably want

Partition Key: portfolioId
Sort Key : transactionId

You can do a Query with partition key of a portfolioId and you would get the most recent transactions for that portfolio.

If you also need to get a user's most recent transactions, create a GSI with partition key userId and sort key of transactionId.

It almost never makes sense to combine to Ids in the partition key. In can make sense to join IDs in the sort key.

Comment: for part 2, think you meant `transactionDate` not `transactionId`

Comment: I made an update in the question to add the fact the app does not query all portfolios for one user, except for the portfolio table itself, then resources are loaded per portfolio... the examples in my update are for tables that relate to a (one) portfolio...